# Jquery: Probably a syntax Issue in ajax() method - Value not getting sent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm able to dump value of the variable message in console .

But im not able to send it off in POST Request.

AJAX call:

```
chat.throwmsg = function(message) {
if ($.trim(message).length != 0) {
    console.log(message);
   $.ajax({
       url: 'ajax/chat.php',
       type: 'post',
       data: { method: 'throw', message: message} ,
       success: function(data) {
           chat.fetchmsgs();
           $('textarea#entry').val('');
       }
}); 
}
}
```

This maybe due to wrong syntax, but I've tried both single and double quotes, and combination as well .

Comment: Do you see any error in console?

Comment: are you sure the method is getting called

Comment: put console logs in success method and server side in php as well

Comment: It works fine as is for me while testing. It must either be an error in your chat.php (which you should test seperately) or something before this code...

Answer (score 0):

With a wild assumption, you are not having any error messages in developer console and  chat.php has a post handler forthese parameters

Since your data is JSON, please change the code as this way and have a try..

```
   var temp={ method: 'throw', message: message};
   var param=JSON.stringify(temp);
   $.ajax({
       url: 'ajax/chat.php',
       type: 'post',
       data: param ,
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(data) {
           chat.fetchmsgs();
           $('textarea#entry').val('');
       }
   });
```

Answer (score -1):

after reviewing the code I could not find any issues that restrict the data to be sent along with ajax request,if you are having any syntax errors you should have been warned prior the request initialization, however I recommend you to check the request header in the network tab of browser console and see your sending data along with the request if it's there you probably need to check the code of getting the post data in your server-side implementations